# How to get localized values from Facebook Open Graph API through Koala?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, translation, koala-gem

I am using the koala gem in my rails app to use the Facebook Open Graph API. 
The primary language of the app is German.

Is there a way to set a locale to get e.g. the user's current city in German? Or is there another reliable wa to translate locations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Graph API supports the passing of the `locale` parameter. For Germany, this would be `de_DE`.

You can test this via

```
GET /me?fields=location&locale=de_DE
```

compared to

```
GET /me?fields=location&locale=en_GB
```

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#readmodifiers
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/

Keep in mind that the translations are not always available, especially for OpenGraph objects.

Comment: Good start! Thanks! But i didnt find any configuration of Koala to set the locale as described :(

Comment: According to https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L40 you should be able to pass `locale=de_DE` as argument to the `get_object()` call. I'm not a Ruby expert...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/
is no longer working