# Modify Relay default network layer on the fly

Tags: javascript, react-native, relay

I have a React-Native app that aims to do multilingual support.

It uses `Relay`, so I have code like this above the root component.

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer("http://localhost/graphql"))
```

Now, the language parameter is passed via parameter as [Facebook does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903860/4776002) with their Graph API.

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer("http://localhost/graphql?locale=en_US"))
```

How can I change this on the fly when the app's language can be changed from the settings? And how would one, in a sense, restart the app with those language changes?
I might just be confusing myself by trying to implement for the first time `relay` and `react-native-router-flux` at the same time....

This is the root container code in its entirety:

```
import Relay, {
  DefaultNetworkLayer,
  RootContainer,
} from 'react-relay'
import RelayRenderer from 'rnrf-relay-renderer'
import {
    Actions,
    Reducer,
    Router,
    Scene
} from 'react-native-router-flux'

const locale = `en_US`
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer(`http://localhost/graphql?locale=${locale}`))

const reducerCreate = params => {
    const defaultReducer = Reducer(params)
        return (state, action) => {
            return defaultReducer(state, action)
        }
    }
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router
                createReducer={reducerCreate}
                wrapBy={RelayRenderer()}
            >
                ...
                ...
            </Router>
        )
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a header that specifies the locale for language.

Comment: This should be a comment